# Logout seems to not invalidate session in Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: logout, azure-static-web-app

I created a static Web site using **Azure Static Web Apps** (under the Free plan for now -- not sure if that's relevant to the issue at hand.) I can access the Web site through an `***.azurestaticapps.net` URL.

I then tried to test **Azure Active Directory authentication** per Microsoft's instruction from this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization

My problem is that **logging out does not seems to work as I would expect on a normal Web site.** I could log out, but when I tried to login again (hoping to use a different Azure AD account,) the Microsoft login screen flashes by and **I got logged right back in with the user that I just logged out from.** Switching to a different tab doesn't help.

**Steps to repro:**

1. Navigate to `/.auth/login/aad` and login using a Microsoft Account. Say **NO** to 'Stay signed in?' prompt.
2. Navigate to `/.auth/me` to see the basic information on the logged in account to prove that I'm in the logged in state.
3. Navigate to `/.auth/logout` to logout. Immediately, navigate to `/.auth/me` again to confirm that my static Web App regards me as 'logged out.' I'd see this:

```
{"clientPrincipal": null}
```

4. Navigate to `/.auth/login/aad` again. Microsoft login page flashes by, and I am logged right back in with the previously logged out user.

**Things that *sort of* worked**

Any of the two actions below alone seems to make the browser *forget* my logged-in state:

1. Close the whole browser and relaunch it. I'd get asked to pick the previous user (and then enter the password) or choose a new user. This sort of works but reminds me of some Web sites 15-20 years ago that said 'For security reasons, please don't forget to close your *entire* browser after logging out from this one tab.'
2. Open a new tab in the same browser, and navigate to `hotmail.com`. That tab will *enjoy* my logged-in state from the Static Web Apps tab. I'd see my mails right away. Then I log out from the `hotmail.com` tab, switch back to `***.azurestaticapps.net` tab and see that I am still logged into my Static Web App. Good! Then if I log out from my Static Web App and try to log back in, **it has forgotten my logged-in state this time**. In other words, **logging out from the `hotmail.com` tab is somehow more powerful.**

I also tested `/.auth/login/google` too and **the same problem arises!** So the issue seems to be on the Azure Static Web Apps side, not how idPs handle their logout process.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: **Update** This 'auto login' behavior will NOT happen if that browser has more than one 'signed-in' Microsoft Accounts. (I didn't test Google.) With more than one signed-in accounts, the Static Web App couldn't pick one to use, and ask the user to pick.

Comment: I've been banging my head against this same issue for weeks.  Did you ever resolve it?